# Create dynamic media player Android

Tags: java, android, stream, streaming, media-player

I tried to make a streaming radio application. I used service for the media player. How when radio1 is playing, i click radio2, radio1 is stop and play radio2 ? (sorry for my bad english :D)
This is my code

MyRadio.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyRadio extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button radio1, radio2,  stop;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_service);
    radio1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    radio2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    radio1.setOnClickListener(this);
    radio2.setOnClickListener(this);
    stop.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
        i.putExtra(MyService.URL, "http://5.231.68.21:8004");
        startService(i);
        break;

    case R.id.button3:
        Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
        j.putExtra(MyService.URL, "http://50.117.121.163:80");
        startService(j);
        break;

    case R.id.button2:
        stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
        break;
    }

}
  }
```

MyService.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MyService extends Service implements
    MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {

public static String URL;
private MediaPlayer mp;

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String i = intent.getStringExtra(URL);
    String url = "" + i;
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(url);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.prepareAsync();

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

public void onDestroy() {
    mp.stop();
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mp.start();
}

public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
    mp = null;
    return true;
}
 }
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What does happen instead? What problem are you facing? The question is unclear to me in its current form.

Comment: My problem when radio1 is playing, I click radio2, radio2 played and radio1 do not stop. So, radio1 and radio2 play together. I want when I click radio2, radio1 stop played..

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you push a button you're creating a new instance of the MediaPlayer and telling it to play a song.  You're never destroying/stopping the one you created before.

Comment: thanks for answer @Vintral.. problem solved.
can you help me for this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627147/how-to-show-progress-dialog-from-service)?